# How to get grid cell value in to modal by click on any cell inside angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How do I get the grid cell value into modal by clicking on a cell inside `Angular ui-grid`?

I am using the [UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/) plugin.

Comment: Could you update this question with a simple example of what you are doing/trying, along with the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

yes thanks for your response @Meir, i can't provide code because getting data into grid from back end without back end data we can't test , but finally got the solution using row.entity.columnvalue[coming from backend), by doing this i am getting value into template

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
        { name: 'username', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-model="row.entity.username" ng-click="grid.appScope.showMe(row.entity.username)">{{row.entity.username}}</div>'}]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the cell is editable or not. If it is, listen to a beginCellEdit event, you should get the row and column in the event and you can get the actual value and open your modal.
If you prefer not to use and editable grid, use a cellTemplate with ng-click="..." that passes as a parameter the column name. Note that you might need to use appScope in your ng-click code.

If you put a more specific example, I might be able to narrow down the answer.